# Создание multi-page editor в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, плагин

Надо создать плагин для eclipse на основе шаблона Multi-Page editor. Начал идти по этой инструкции 
http://www.wideskills.com/eclipse-plugin-tutorial/eclipse-plugin-editors-tutorial
но застрял на моменте

> In order to view the editor in action launch eclipse runtime
>   application. Create a new file from right click context menu.Name the
>   new file anything but keep the extension of the “.mpe” because this is
>   the extension with which newly created editor is associated with. Once
>   you have created the file – Sample Multi-Page editor will open up with
>   three tabs namely .mpe, Properties and Preview. Play around
>   with the editor before we get onto reviewing generated code.

В момент создания вылазит меню [image]

И я совершенно не понимаю, что нужно ввести в первой строке. При нажатии на Browse я вижу пустоту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё осложняется тем, что с eclipse я на "Вы". Как довети до конца начатое?

**UPD: Проблема решена!**
Не могу внятно объяснить, потому что её решила не я. Кажетс, во время runtime сначала надо было создать проект, а уже потом лезть создавать сам док.